# Can "multiplying" two groups $H,K$ give a group $G$ of order $|G| \le |H|$ or $|G| \le |K|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Can "multiplying" two groups $H,K$ give a group $G$ of order $|G| \le |H|$ or $|G |\le  |K|$

Obviously by multiplying I mean applying some group operation.

**Specifically, I'm trying to understand why for $H \le P$ where $P$ is a $p$-subgroup, $HK=K$ for $K$ being a sylow $p$ subgroup.**

Comment: Since $H$ and $K$ are each contained in $HK$ (as they both contain $e$), their product is of order at least $\max(|H|,|K|)$. So $HP$ has order at least $|P|$, and is a $p$-group, hence has order at most $|P|$, giving the equality. The key there isn't whether it can be smaller, it's that it cannot be *bigger* (whereas in an arbitrary product $HK$, you could get something strictly larger than $|H|$ or $|K|$).

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the statement is missing some assumption, since the product $HK$ need not be a subgroup in general. In fact, if $H$ and $K$ are two Sylow $p$-subgroups your statement would imply $H = HK = K$ which is clearly not always the case.